# Ubuntu sendmail only sends to localhost

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, sendmail

I have set up a LAMP server with sendmail on Ubuntu 14.04.
When sending mail, either from terminal or PHP mail(), it won't work properly.

When I use `mail("user@localhost","test","test");` it sends it correctly, and I can read the message with `mail` from terminal, but when sending to Gmail address, message won't go trough. 
Same outcome when using `"test" | mail -s "test" xyz@gmail.com"` from server terminal.

Any idea how to fix this?

I have been Googling for several hours now, I have tried everything without finding working solution, and I'm starting to lose hope.

Comment: this one will help you to send email from localhost ubuntu.  http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/03/send-e-mail-localhost-ubuntu-php/

Answer (score 3):

If you're running Ubuntu here is a much simpler solution:

issue from command line >

```
apt-get install ssmtp
```

Then edit the configuration file in `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`

A sample configuration to use your gmail for sending e-mails:

```
# root is the person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
root=your@email.com

# Here is the gmail configuration (or change it to your private smtp server)
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587 (leave this the way it is)
AuthUser=your@gmail.com (just change this) 
AuthPass=yourGmailPass  (and change the password for your gmail account)
UseTLS=YES (leave this the way it is)
UseSTARTTLS=YES (leave this the way it is)
```

Note: Make sure the "mail" command is present in your system. mailutils package should provide this one in Debian based systems.

Then try send emails again, send it to another domain @gmail, @aol, @yahoo, @privatedomain besides localhost email addresses.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I want to send email from my LAMP server with PHP mail(), which seems impossible counting the solutions I'v tried

Comment: you need to do this first, LAMP uses Linux mail software to send emails with php's mail() function. this fixes the smtp issue, once its fixed, next time when you use php to send email with the mail() function, it will send it to any domain.

Comment: So you say I need own Gmail account to set my LAMP server to send mails via Google's SMTP server? Doesn't sound right.

Comment: it depends on the network. at my work network, any time i launch an ubuntu instance i can start sending email to anyone without further configuration; at home, when I launch linux boxes and try to use the php's email function, i need to setup an smtp relay.

Comment: Why on earth is this made so difficult. I'll check that soon and reply if it worked, or if universe has something against me.

Answer (score 1):

There're tons of possible problems, so you need to get some logs of error that happening.

Most probably, Google just rejects your email as your server is not correctly configured.

Comment: I won't get any logs. PHP only logs that mail is sent, and no other logs can be found :/
It's not only Google, it won't send mail to any other server. I'v tried multiple servers to send emails to, still nothing.

Comment: What about */var/log/mail.log*? It should contain some useful information, if PHP passed that email to your sendmail.

Comment: Nope, it only says that mail has been accepted for delivery, no errors or anything usefull at all, email still not going trough